# Consuming Client-Side Encrypted Data from Snowflake

Tags: encryption, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to ingest client side encrypted data files from S3 to Snowflake, and want to query the data in Snowflake in readable format using Snowflake SQLs.

I have encrypted the data file using AES 256 and placed in S3. Also, followed the pre requisites of setting up my external stage with MASTER_KEY (AES-256, base64 encoded). However when I read data, it does not show me in readable format.

I would like to know if client side encrypted data can be read in the clear in Snowflake with the right authentication and authorization (without having to unload them back to S3).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you follow these steps? https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-encryption.html#ingesting-client-side-encrypted-data-into-snowflake "The following SQL snippet creates an example Amazon S3 stage object in Snowflake that supports client-side encryption" (please share your code)